# PHP: die or check results?

Tags: php, ldap, exit, die

I am implementing LDAP with PHP which is going fairly easily I must say. However I have a question regarding the use of `die()` or checking function returns. From the below code ([taken from here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php)), what is the point of checking for `$ldapconn` if you use `die()` with the `ldap_connect`? Isn't PHP supposed to exit with `die()` if something goes wrong with `ldap_connect` anyway?

```
// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap.example.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't serve any purpose. ldap_connect will return false if it fails thus die, so you can delete one of the 2.

I would suggest to delete the die and add some good error handling.

Source: [PHP ldap_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php)

You should be careful with testing ldap_connect in PHP5.3 I can successfully connect to any server ( existing or not ) where ldap_connect always returns true. The link type is always ldap_connection but may not actually work / be successful. I'd suggest verifying the connection is valid with @ldap_bind then check for errors.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, that's pretty redundant.

As an aside, you should only ever `die` in mockup prototypes or really simple CLI scripts. For "real" websites, you should handle errors more gracefully and output proper error pages instead of just `die`ing.

Comment: there may be code below the _if ($ldapconn) {}_ statement which would be executed without die(). but you are right, die() is not a proper error handling.

Answer (score 0):

ldap_connect() returns false if the connection fails. In this case the script is stopped by die() and a message is returned. No other code below this line will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

ldap_connect returns false on error. The die is of good use over there because with it you will be able set a readable error/warning for the developer to see.